# Using TimeSeriesForecast for forecasting the traffic growth

Tags: time-series

Have a look to the real traffic growth data ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmv_C2_J7uG8zIhxe5aYZbg79MREI8ePsFJTStSKEeE/edit?usp=sharing)) of a this website. I was thinking to use Mathematica to do a `TimeSeriesForecast` and plot the forecast.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your problem in getting the data from the Google spreadsheet into Mathematica, or is your problem in the use of `TimeSeriesForecast` on the imported data?

Comment: @celtschk: Copying the data from Excel / Google is already a problem. I've never used Mathematica with external data.

Comment: What [Time Series Processes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeSeriesProcesses.html) do you want to use for the forecast?

Comment: @Karsten7.: that's a very good question. I'm not very skilled on this part of Mathematica, I've just started to study it. I was thinking to use TimeSeriesModelFit do you think it would fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the data from the link in your post in [`TSV`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/TSV.html) format.
Importing and preprocessing the data

```
data = MapAt[DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] &,
  Import["D:\\Analytics www.superinformati.com Panoramica del pubblico 20141201-20150303 - Sheet 1.tsv"][[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
 , {All, 1}]
```

Doing the [`TimeSeriesModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesModelFit.html) without specifying a process.

```
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data]
```

> [image]

Plotting the time series together with a 30 day forecast.

```
DateListPlot[{tsm["TemporalData"], TimeSeriesForecast[tsm, {30}]}]
```

> [image]

Without a specified process `TimeSeriesModelFit` choose a [`SARIMAProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SARIMAProcess.html). A similar process but without seasonality is the [`ARIMAProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ARIMAProcess.html) process.

```
tsm2 = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, "ARIMA"]
```

> [image]

```
DateListPlot[{tsm2["TemporalData"], TimeSeriesForecast[tsm2, {30}]}]
```

> [image]

To get the forecast for one year as a function on can use

```
fsfFunc = TimeSeriesForecast[tsm2, {365}]["PathFunction"]

fsfFunc[AbsoluteTime@{2016, 1, 1}]
```

> `187.706`

Comment: It's really really cool, thanks a lot. Is it possible also to have a longer forecast, like in 1 year? Or having the equation of the asymptotic line given in the last image?

Comment: To get the forecast for one year you just have to change the number of time steps ahead to 356 ([see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DuUFS.png)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a last question.. is it possible also to get the unseasonalized data graph for the data instead that only for the forecast? See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78279/deseasonalize-the-data-of-traffic-growth-for-the-past-data

Comment: @Revious See my last comment and the edit. These should answer your question. If you want a linear function that approximates the forecast, just do a fit to `TimeSeriesForecast[tsm2, {365}]["Path"]`.

Comment: Thanks and congratulations for your skill on Mathematica!