# Deseasonalize the data of traffic growth for the past data

Tags: data, time-series

In another question ([Using TimeSeriesForecast for forecasting the traffic growth](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77229/using-timeseriesforecast-for-forecasting-the-traffic-growth/78275)) I asked to use the TimeSeriesForecast on [this set of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmv_C2_J7uG8zIhxe5aYZbg79MREI8ePsFJTStSKEeE/edit?usp=sharing) the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77229/using-timeseriesforecast-for-forecasting-the-traffic-growth/78275#78275) provided the plot **with** and **without** the **seasonalization** for the future value.

Is it possible to get the same plot (without seasonalization) for data which are already available (now this is only for the forecasted one)?

**EDIT**

The SARIMA model has the seasonal peaks. Is it possible to calculate the same model also for the range of dates on which I provided the data?

If that is possible maybe I could use the model of the periodic peaks to modulate the real data getting rid of the data seasonality.

What I would be curious to get is not a regression (which would be a flat line) but the deseasonalized data.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is *stagionalization*?

Comment: @Pickett: sorry, my english is terrible. I meant seasonalization, I will correct. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with deseasonalized without making a regression. Do you mean filtering or smoothing? Or something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UHPUJ.png), [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vYDqv.png) or [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkb7M.png), which are all different kinds of regressions?

Comment: @Karsten7. I am not sure if what I want can be achieved. I will edit the question. ps: how did you managed to get the 3 images?

Comment: The last one was created using something like what I show in my answer. The other two were produced by fitting a function, that is not a straight line, to the data (, but this is still doing a linear regression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing seasonality by using [`MeanFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeanFilter.html?q=MeanFilter):

```
data = MapAt[DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] &,
 Import["D:\\Analytics www.superinformati.com Panoramica del pubblico 20141201-20150303 - Sheet 1.tsv"][[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
 , {All, 1}]

DateListPlot[{data, 
 Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], MeanFilter[data[[All, 2]], 7]}]}]
```

> [image: MeanFiltered]

Comment: I used a range of 7 for the `MeanFilter`, as the `SARIMA` model revealed a seasonal order of 7 and because assuming a weekly seasonality makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And really great job, if you want there is also a last question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78311/how-to-investigate-the-seasonality-of-the-data

Comment: How could you see that the seasonality is 7 days?

Answer (score 3):

Your description of what you want to do is quite vague and the "not a regression" part is kind of contradictory. Therefore I'll take

> "Is it possible to calculate the same model also for the range of dates on which I provided the data?"

part to formulate an answer.

Importing your data saved in TSV format

```
data = MapAt[DateString[{#, {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}}] &,
 Import["D:\\Analytics www.superinformati.com Panoramica del pubblico 20141201-20150303 - Sheet 1.tsv"][[3 ;;, {1, 2}]]
 , {All, 1}]
```

Finding the SARIMA process

```
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data]
```

One can use [`RandomFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomFunction.html?q=RandomFunction) to create multiple simulations assuming a random process. The following code produces 5 simulations. I use `Length@data - 30` because your data looks like the real trend starts somewhere after 30 days.

```
rf1 = RandomFunction[tsm["BestFit"], {Length@data - 30}, 5]
```

Creating a plot of these simulations and of their mean

```
randomP1 = 
 DateListPlot[Transpose[{data[[30 ;;, 1]], #}] & /@ rf1["States"], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[1/2], 
  PlotRange -> {{data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, Automatic}]

meanP1 = DateListPlot[
  Transpose[{data[[30 ;;, 1]], TimeSeriesThread[Mean, rf1]["PathStates"]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, Automatic}]
```

Putting everything into one plot

```
Show[{randomP1,
 DateListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]],
 meanP1}]
```

> [image: SARIMA]

Doing the same using a ARIMA model

```
tsm2 = TimeSeriesModelFit[data, "ARIMA"]    

rf2 = RandomFunction[tsm2["BestFit"], {Length@data - 30}, 5]

randomP2 = 
 DateListPlot[Transpose[{data[[30 ;;, 1]], #}] & /@ rf2["States"], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[1/2], 
  PlotRange -> {{data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, Automatic}]

meanP2 = DateListPlot[
  Transpose[{data[[30 ;;, 1]], TimeSeriesThread[Mean, rf2]["PathStates"]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, Automatic}]

Show[{randomP2,
 DateListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]],
 meanP2}]
```

> [image: ARIMA]

Comment: Increasing the number of simulations from 5 to a much higher number will create [a much smoother line for the mean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bum30.png).